# phrase not found in nltk wordnet but found via the princeton wordnetweb online search

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, wordnet

This is probably dumb but I cannot seem to find words like "wheeled vehicle" via `wn.synsets('wheeled vehicle')` (`wn` created via `from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn`) --- returns empty array, but I could however find it on the [princeton wordnetweb online search](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?o2=&o0=1&o8=1&o1=1&o7=&o5=&o9=&o6=&o3=&o4=&s=wheeled+vehicle)

Might anyone know what I'm missing? Or recommend better libraries?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For multi word lemmas, use underscore instead of whitespaces.

```
>>> from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn

# Retrieve the synsets that're associated with lemma "wheeled vehicle"
>>> wn.synsets('wheeled_vehicle')
[Synset('wheeled_vehicle.n.01')]

>>> wn.synsets('wheeled_vehicle')[0].definition()
u'a vehicle that moves on wheels and usually has a container for transporting things or people'
```

To access the synset directly, you need to know the POS and the lemma index of the synset:

```
>>> wn.synset('wheeled_vehicle.n.01')
Synset('wheeled_vehicle.n.01')
```